# Координаты Картинки. Игра ТИР

Tags: delphi, разработка-игр, координаты, if

Начинающий.
Хочу переделать игру Тир (популярную в исходниках)
под свою, вместо

```
Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;     // цвет линий
Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;  // цвет закраски
// рисуем рожицу
Canvas.Ellipse(x,y,x+30,Y+30);       // лицо
Canvas.Ellipse(x+9,y+10,x+11,y+13);  // левый глаз
Canvas.Ellipse(x+19,y+10,x+21,y+13); // правый глаз
Canvas.Arc(x+4,y+4,x+26,y+26,x,y+20,x+30,y+20); // улыбка
```

нарисованного смайлика добавил картинку, у меня не ловит попадания на картинку. Проблема с координатами цели. Подскажите, что исправить, что дописать.

Код:

```
var

  Form1: TForm1;
     fx,fy: integer;  // координаты рожицы
  n: integer;      // количество щелчков кнопкой мыши
  p: integer;      // количество попаданий

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Image1.Left:=Random(384);
Image1.Top:=Random(384);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
 n:=n+1;  // кол-во щелчков

  if (x > fx) and (x < fx) and
     (y > fy) and (y < fy)
 then begin
       // щелчок по рожице
       p:=p+1;
       end;
  if n = 10 then
    begin
        // игра закончена

        ShowMessage('Выстрелов: 10. Попаданий: ' +
                 IntToStr(p)+'.');

        // теперь кнопка и сообщение снова видны
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Там вот так:
 if (x > fx) and (x < fx+30) and
     (y > fy) and (y < fy+30)
У меня не окружность, а картинка квадратная. У меня еще проблема, не считает количество промахов...

Answer (score 2):

if (x > fx) and (x < fx) and (y > fy) and (y < fy) - и когда это условие выполнится? 1>2 и 1<2 одновременно быть не может.

У вас круг - берите стандартную формулу для определения принадлежности точки кругу. (x-fx)^2+(y-fy)^2<=R^2